# ! Missing } inserted. <inserted text> }

Tags: latex

I'm writing TeX files on overleaf, and suddenly I got an error:

```
<inserted text> 
              }
l.1355 \end{thebibliography}
                                
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
```

It says the error happens in bbl file. I checked it and the code is:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{100}
 ...
\bibitem{Zargham2020b}
\BIBentryALTinterwordspacing
M.~Zargham, K.~Paruch, and J.~Shorish, ``{Economic Games as Estimators},'' in
  \emph{Mathematical Research for Blockchain Economy}.\hskip 1em plus 0.5em
  minus 0.4em\relax Springer, Cham, 2020, pp. 125--142. [Online]. Available:
  \url{http://link.springer.com/10.1007/978-3-030-53356-4_8}
\BIBentrySTDinterwordspacing

\end{thebibliography}
```

There is a red line under \end{thebibliography}, reporting the same issue.
In the main.tex, I used these commands:

```
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
...
\bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

Could someone help me to figure it out?

ASSOCIATED QUESTION: I found a simple code reporting the same issue, but I still have no idea why "\cite(xyz)" could work normally while "\cite(abc)" shows the error. Below are the code:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@misc{abc,
title="title one",
author="yo{\iffalse}\fi u",
publisher="someone"}

@misc{xyz,
title="title two",
author="me",
publisher="zzz"}

\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
something about \cite{abc} and also \cite{xyz}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

I'd appreciate it if you could help me!

Comment: You might want to post this on [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @soupless Thanks! I'll have a look there!

Comment: @HaopengSong Please make a [mre] including all the necessary packages and code to reproduce the error. Please add this code as text and not as image!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz  Sure, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Can you make one example document which we can copy and paste to reproduce your problem instead of these incomplete code fragments?

Comment: @ samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yes I found the same issue in a short code. I've updated it in the question. Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the update! The code `{\iffalse}\fi` is the problem. It makes no real sense. How should the result look like?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Wow, you really hit the point! I cleaned the cache and deleted this code, it works as normal now! Thank you so much!

Comment: @HaopengSong You're welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `{\iffalse}\fi` in the `abc` bib entry. This syntax makes no sense, just remove it.

```
@misc{abc,
title="title one",
author="yo u",
publisher="someone"}

@misc{xyz,
title="title two",
author="me",
publisher="zzz"}
```